# What is the connection between permutation tests and rank tests?

Tags: references, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, permutation-test

I was trying to understand the null hypothesis of the Wilcoxon rank sum test and thought that the null distribution of the rank sum could be obtained by a permutation test/Monte Carlo test.

If this was truly giving the correct p-values, it seems to me that the Wilcoxon rank sum test would somehow have to have  the permutation distribution baked in. Is this true?

And more general: how do the permutation tests and [rank tests](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_test) relate?

- Also this lecture https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/stats/stats200/stats200.1172/Lecture09.pdf describes some symmetry connection between rank tests and permutation tests. Why does looking at a pooled rank imply that the null distribution is a permutation distribution?
- https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4614-4818-1_12 claims on page 460 that the "linear rank statistic used by popular rank tests is clearly a subclass of permutation statistic [used in permutation tests]" how do I understand this? Could somebody elaborate more?

Comment: Yes, rank tests are permutation tests based on the ranks!

Comment: That is lovely. Do you have a source which says so in as nice and plain English as you did? :) I was looking for quite some time and could not find it

Comment: In reference  https://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/442s02/notes/ch7a.pdf  we find *All the
common non-parametric rank tests are permutation tests carried out
on ranks. Fisher’s exact test is a permutation test for categorical data.*. Will try to find something published ...

Comment: That's enough of an answer, I guess, @kjetilbhalvorsen (+1), if you wish.